# Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value

Tags: android-studio, installation, android-virtual-device

I just started to install Android Studio, but I am finding it difficult. Now I'm stuck trying to enable an AVD at the emulator.

As you can see at the image below, variables are set and SDK tools and environment are updated. I'm using Windows 10 with AMD (HyperV virtualization enabled). What more can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's solved. The issue comes because of Windows 10 Spanish version sets as default username Tú. Creating a folder at C:\Users\Tú

The accent breaks the AVD giving the error at the picture. We should change our username, rename the folder and swap all the windows registry entries referencing to the folder.

If you have this issue, maybe this video would help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=35&v=J_rTOA4gXJI&feature=emb_title

Comment: I would regard this as a bug, and it would be good to report it. It may be reported already, but perhaps worth checking?

Comment: If you wish to mark this as "solved", click the tick/check mark on the left of your answer, so that it turns green.

Comment: Ty, both, ill report it :) and ill tick it, but now says to me I'm not able to do it till 13 hours later.